# How can I play multiple tracks simultaneously in SoundCloud JavaScript SDK 3.0.0?

Tags: soundcloud

How can I play multiple tracks simultaneously in JavaScript SDK 3.0.0 ?

```
SC.stream('/tracks/' + trackID1)
  .then(function(player) {
    player.play();
  });

setTimeout(function() {
  SC.stream('/tracks/' + trackID2)
    .then(function(player) {

      /*** track2 is played after stopping track1 ***/
      player.play();

    });
}, 5000);
```

I can do it in JavaScript SDK 2.0.0.

```
SC.stream('/tracks/' + trackID1, function(player) {
  player.play();
});

setTimeout(function() {
  SC.stream('/tracks/' + trackID2, function(player) {

    /*** track2 is played without stopping track1 ***/
    player.play();

  });
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. For a wellformed question should provide code you've tried (you did this, thats good), errors you get (you did not), expected and actual results (you didn't do that too). Have you looked into the API docs if the methods exist? What errors do you get? Do you hear anything?

Comment: Thank you for your advice.

I expect that track2 is played without stopping track1 in JavaScript SDK 3.0.0.

I couldn't get errors in browser console.

I couldn't find about it in the API docs. https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks

Comment: Why not html with autoplay?

Answer (score 0):

This is how:

```
var scplayers = [];

SC.stream("/tracks/"+sctrack.id, {autoLoad: true}).then(function(player){
  player.options.debug = true;
  player.options.useSinglePlayer = false;
  //this sets a separate id for the same track so it gets handled as a
  //separate track
  player.options.soundId = 111; //ignore if the tracks are always different
  scplayers[0] = player;
});
SC.stream("/tracks/"+sctrack.id, {autoLoad: true}).then(function(player){
  player.options.debug = true;
  player.options.useSinglePlayer = false;
  //this sets a separate id for the same track so it gets handled as a
  //separate track
  player.options.soundId = 222; //ignore if the tracks are always different
  scplayers[1] = player;
});
scplayers[0].play();
scplayers[1].play();
```

As an extra I added the soundId part. This allows you to play the same track multiple times with offset and what not.